# How can I order columns horizontally by columns called OnHandX in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is shown quantities ordered from highest to lowest horizontally by the column named OnHand1, OnHand2, OnHand3...

[image]

How can I order from the lowest to highest ingoring the columns that are in quantity zero?

Thanks a lot

Comment: This is a denormalized design, you should have another table of `Loc, OnHand, Saldo` and a foreign key to this table

Comment: What happens when someone has more hands that you have columns? Fix your design, normalise your table(s). Clearly you have a one to many relationship here so there should be at least 2 tables involved.

Comment: I can't modified the table, is used in an application during 20 years, that's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: You've seriously had this in production for 20 years and only now need to do this? Maybe create a view that manufactures your OnHandX column using some nested case expressions?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.